# Xamarin IOS Push Killed app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Push =>

```
{{
aps =     {
    alert =         {
        "loc-args" =             (
        );
        "loc-key" = "new_chat";
    };
    "content-available" = 1;
    id = 3;
    message = Aaa;
    sound = default;
    subject = "new_chat";
    type = chat;
};
```

}}

When the application is killed and I receive a push notification it is shown with the text "new_chat". How can I change it to another text?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are targeting iOS 10+, you can add a Notification Services extension app (`UNNotificationServiceExtension`) to your app bundle.

> modifies the content of a remote notification before it is delivered to the user.

In the `DidReceiveNotificationRequest` override, extract your content from the `UNNotificationRequest` and modify it and return it via the contentHandler provided.

Required reading to understand how/when the extension is used:

- [Modifying Content in Newly Delivered Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications?language=objc)

Also:

Xamarin Docs: [iOS Extensions in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/extensions)

Apple docs: [UNNotificationServiceExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension?language=objc)